# Xcode 3.1.3 - Organizer The device is not activated. Please activate it using iTunes

Tags: iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, itunes

I recently upgraded my XCode SDK to version 3.1.3 and my iPhone OS to 3.0. It is important to note that everything was working fine when I had OS version 2.2.1 in my iPhone. My iPhone Touch device is not jailbroken and I have a valid provisioning profile in the organizer which is linked to my iPhone Touch however it has a yellow circle next to it.

This is because in the organizer under devices it displays the ipod with version 3.0 (7A341) and then it Reads (in the section where the provisioning profiles should go):

> This device is not activated. Please activate it using iTunes.

When I go in xcode and build the application it does so just fine, and the code signing is in fact assigned to the correct provisioning profile. But whenever I try to run it in the device I get "No provisioned iPhone OS device is connected.". This is because the organizer keeps telling me to activate the device using iTunes.

I have iTunes version 8.2 and the device is there and i can sync it just fine, however it keeps displaying that message in XCode. I have tried restoring my ipod about 10 times but I always get the same result, I have also tried powering off the iphone Touch and the computer but nothing seems to help.

Does anyone else have this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue, but I have an ipod touch version 2.2.1. It used to connect to Xcode 3.1.2, then I upgraded to 3.1.3 and it doesn't work. I reverted back to 3.1.2 and it does not work. It does work on a friends mac with 3.1.3 so there is something wrong with my iMac. Firewall is disabled. It connects to iTunes fine and it is activated. Just won't show up in the organizer. Rebooting does not work. I reset, and restored it and it still doesn't connect. The fact that it connects to a friends mac and not mine leads me to believe that upgrading the ipod to version 3.0 would not fix the issue.

Jimi

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/index.action#downloads
download and install it
Leopard Downloads

```
* iPhone SDK 3.1.3 with Xcode 3.1.4
* iPhone SDK 3.1.3 with Xcode 3.1.4 Readme
```

open mac terminal

> $ ln -s /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.1.2\ (7D11)/ /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.1.3

my space write in here
http://leefj.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!ADF54DD0A549AD9B!462.entry

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to flycomputer i was able to resolve my problem with iphone os update to 3.1.3.
But i didn't need to make the symlink so check if it's done by itself or not before lunching the command :

```
$ ln -s /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.1.2\ (7D11)/ /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/3.1.3
```

Answer (score 0):

This usually means your Phone is not activated with your provider. Can you actually make phone calls with your iPhone? Did you restore your phone via the XCode Organizer or iTunes?

Answer (score 0):

Well it is not actually a phone it is an iPod Touch. I tried to restore it both via Xcode Organizer and iTunes with the same results.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the error I get, but try rebooting the iPod.  Hold down the sleep/wake button on the top for a few seconds.  When it asks if you want to turn off the device, move the slider to turn it off.  I usually wait a minute and power it back on.  This always works for me.

Answer (score -3):

You are probably behind a firewall, with anti-spyware protection activated.
iTunes needs to connect properly to web (Apple, I guess) in order to activate correctly your device.
Disable the firewall, then launch iTunes, that worked for me.

JR

Comment: you have no idea what you are talking about.